# Extracting the data from inline javaScript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

Inline java script on web page that i am scraping is generating data and feeds corresponding div with telephone numbers. Web page source does not show numbers, therefore i am unable to scrape the data using x-path, beautiful soup etc. While analyzing page source i discovered that JavaScript has numbers generated only inside script in page source and they are not visible unles the page source get saved. This is particular script:

```
<script>
QuidditaEnvironment.CurrentContactData={"ContactInfoName":null,"PhoneNumber1":"064/005-3708","PhoneNumber2":null,"City":null,"Address":"","Email":"srdjanmilosevickiseli@gmail.com","ShowOtherContactData":false,"ShowContactPhone":true,"ShowMyAdsPage":false,"Advertiser":{"DisplayName":"korisnik-404772","PartyType":1,"Comment":null,"CreatedAt":"2014-10-27T10:31:01","LastModifiedAt":"2014-10-27T10:31:01","ActivatedAt":"2014-10-27T10:32:13","IsDeleted":false,"IsHost":false,"ProfileDescription":null,"AccountBalance":0.0,"AccountBalanceString":null,"AvatarImageURL":null,"IsAvatarValid":false,"AvatarImages":null,"ContactInfos":[{"Name":"Glavni","Address":"Beograd,Zage Malivuk 2 008","ZipCode":null,"City":null,"Country":null,"Phone1":null,"Phone2":null,"Longitude":null,"Latitude":null,"Email":"srdjanmilosevickiseli@gmail.com","CreatedAt":"2014-10-27T10:31:01","LastModifiedAt":"2014-10-27T10:32:13","IsPrimary":true,"IsActive":true,"ShowOnMyAdsPage":true,"SequenceNumber":1,"ForHost":false,"Id":404772,"Version":3}],"StateName":"Aktivan","StateId":2,"IsInvestor":false,"IsSchool":false,"PartyGroupIds":[],"PartyGroupNames":[],"Address":null,"AdvertisingParty":true,"BlockAds":false,"NumberOfCVs":0,"EnforceIdentityUniqueness":true,"Slug":"korisnik-404772","Email":null,"SuppressAutomaticVerification":false,"Id":404772,"Version":4},"Latitudes":[],"Longitudes":[],"InvestorRoute":"nekretnine/novogradnja/korisnik-404772/projekti","UserAdsRoute":null,"SchoolRoute":"oglasi/korisnik-404772/posao/kursevi-i-obuke-pretraga","AvatarUrl":null,"NumberInRegister":null,"WebAddress":null,"Id":5425435147525,"Version":225,"Guid":"d93c6d04-5c96-4c80-aefb-fa644b1a1351"};QuidditaEnvironment.IsCurrentAdActive=true;
QuidditaEnvironment.CurrentClassified={"RelativeUrl":"/nekretnine/prodaja-stanova/direktna-prodaja/5425435147525","HasAutomaticRenewal":false,"ValidToProlonged":null,"ShowInUnifiedAdvertiserAdList":true,"IsUsedMoveToTop":false,"ExpiresWithin48Hours":false,"UniqueId":"5425435147525_4","Id":"5425435147525","AdKindId":"4","IsPromoted":false,"IsInterestingInternal":false,"IsInterestingExternal":false,"InterestingEntryDate":null,"AdKindCode":"Premium","AdKindPosition":1,"StateId":101,"StoppageReasonIds":null,"StoppageReasonDescription":null,"Version":0,"Stamp":"2017-06-19T14:33:50.655Z","AdvertiserId":"404772","Title":"DIREKTNA PRODAJA","Text":"Hrastov parket,PVC stolarija,sigurnosna vrata,hodnik,spavaca soba,kupatilo,kuhinja sa prirodnom ventilacijom,dnevni boravak..klima..","TextHtml":"<p>Hrastov parket,PVC stolarija,sigurnosna vrata,hodnik,spavaca soba,kupatilo,kuhinja sa prirodnom ventilacijom,dnevni boravak..klima..</p>","PrintText":"","ContactInfoName":null,"PhoneNumber1":"+381640053708","PhoneNumber2":null,"Email":"True","Address":"","City":null,"ValidFrom":"2017-06-16T13:10:11Z","ValidFromForDisplay":"2017-06-16T13:10:11Z","ValidFromProlonged":null,"ValidTo":"2017-06-23T13:10:11Z","LastPublished":"2017-06-16T13:10:11Z","IsFirstOfKind":false,"CreatedAt":"2015-12-28T15:58:21Z","LastModifiedAt":"2017-06-16T13:09:42Z","IsArchived":false,"GeoLocationRPT":"44.801593,20.527653","ImageCount":6,"ImageURLs":["/slike/oglasi/Originals/160228/direktna-prodaja-uknjizen-stan-5425435147525-71779653263.jpg","/slike/oglasi/Originals/160228/direktna-prodaja-uknjizen-stan-5425435147525-71779653261.jpg","/slike/oglasi/Originals/160228/direktna-prodaja-uknjizen-stan-5425435147525-71779653262.jpg","/slike/oglasi/Originals/160228/direktna-prodaja-uknjizen-stan-5425435147525-71779653264.jpg","/slike/oglasi/Originals/160228/direktna-prodaja-uknjizen-stan-5425435147525-71779653265.jpg","/slike/oglasi/Originals/160228/direktna-prodaja-uknjizen-stan-5425435147525-71779653266.jpg"],"ImageTexts":["","","","","",""],"CategoryIds":[1,2,2001,12],"CategoryId":12,"CategoryHierarchyId":"1.2.2001.12.","CategoryNames":["Nekretnine","Stambeni prostor","Prodaja","Stan"],"CategoryFullName":"Nekretnine>Stambeni prostor>Prodaja>Stan","AdvertiserLogoUrlInternal":null,"AdvertiserLogoUrl":null,"VideoUrl":null,"CreatedByUserId":404772,"DeclarationId":404772,"EnclosureFilePath":null,"ListHTML":"&lt;div class=&quot;col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;row&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;product-item product-list-item Premium real-estates my-ad-placeholder&quot; data-id=&quot;5425435147525&quot; id=&quot;5425435147525&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;my-ad-sticker&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;small-arrow-map-ad&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;central-feature&quot;&gt;&lt;span data-value=&quot;31.000&quot;&gt;&lt;i&gt;31.000&amp;nbsp;€&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;price-shadow&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;/Content/assets/frontend/layout/img/price-shadow.png&quot; style=&quot;width:100%; height:10px;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-4 col-lg-4&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;product-type&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;figure class=&quot;pi-img-wrapper&quot;&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;a-images&quot; href=&quot;/nekretnine/prodaja-stanova/direktna-prodaja/5425435147525&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&#39;https://img.halooglasi.com//slike/oglasi/Thumbs/160228/m/direktna-prodaja-uknjizen-stan-5425435147525-71779653263.jpg&#39; class=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;DIREKTNA PRODAJA&quot; onError=&quot;this.onerror = null; this.src = &amp;#39;/Content/Quiddita/Widgets/Product/Stylesheets/img/no-image.jpg&amp;#39;&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/figure&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;pi-img-wrapper-under&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;publish-date&quot;&gt;16.06.2017&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;basic-info&quot;&gt;&lt;span data-field-name=&#39;oglasivac_nekretnine_s&#39; data-field-value=&#39;vlasnik&#39;&gt;Vlasnik&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;clear&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 sm-margin&quot;&gt;&lt;h3 class=&quot;ad-title&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/nekretnine/prodaja-stanova/direktna-prodaja/5425435147525&quot;&gt;DIREKTNA PRODAJA&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;ul class=&quot;subtitle-places&quot;&gt;&lt;li&gt;Beograd&amp;nbsp;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Opština Zvezdara&amp;nbsp;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Mirijevo&amp;nbsp;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;ul class=&quot;ad-features &quot;&gt;&lt;li class=&#39;col-p-1-3&#39;&gt;&lt;div class=&#39;value-wrapper&#39;&gt;Stan&amp;nbsp;&lt;span class=&#39;legend&#39;&gt;Tip nekretnine&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li class=&#39;col-p-1-3&#39;&gt;&lt;div class=&#39;value-wrapper&#39;&gt;39&amp;nbsp;m&lt;sup&gt;2&lt;/sup&gt;&lt;span class=&#39;legend&#39;&gt;Kvadratura&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li class=&#39;col-p-1-3&#39;&gt;&lt;div class=&#39;value-wrapper&#39;&gt;2.0&amp;nbsp;&lt;span class=&#39;legend&#39;&gt;Broj soba&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;clear&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;p class=&quot;text-description-list ad-description short-desc&quot;&gt;Hrastov parket,PVC stolarija,sigurnosna vrata,hodnik,spavaca soba,kupatilo,kuhinja sa prirodnom ventilacijom,dnevni boravak..klima..&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;btns&quot;&gt;&lt;button type=&quot;button&quot; class=&quot;btn btn-circle btn-fav-ad-star fav-cmd favorite-ad-holder&quot; data-id=&quot;5425435147525&quot;&gt;&lt;/button&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;on-map&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;clear&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;","GridHTML":"&lt;div class=&quot;col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;product-item product-grid-item Premium real-estates my-ad-placeholder&quot;&gt;&lt;figure class=&quot;pi-img-wrapper&quot;&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;a-images&quot; href=&quot;/nekretnine/prodaja-stanova/direktna-prodaja/5425435147525&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&#39;https://img.halooglasi.com//slike/oglasi/Thumbs/160228/m/direktna-prodaja-uknjizen-stan-5425435147525-71779653263.jpg&#39; class=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;DIREKTNA PRODAJA&quot; onError=&quot;this.onerror = null; this.src = &amp;#39;/Content/Quiddita/Widgets/Product/Stylesheets/img/no-image.jpg&amp;#39;&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;on-map&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;wrap-btn-fav&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;btn-group btn-group-solid&quot;&gt;&lt;button type=&quot;button&quot; class=&quot;btn btn-circle btn-fav-ad-star fav-cmd favorite-ad-holder&quot; data-id=&quot;5425435147525&quot;&gt;&lt;/button&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;product-type&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/figure&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;central-feature&quot;&gt;&lt;span data-value=&quot;31.000&quot;&gt;&lt;i&gt;31.000&amp;nbsp;€&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;price-shadow&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;/Content/assets/frontend/layout/img/price-shadow.png&quot; style=&quot;width:100%; height:10px;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;h3 class=&quot;ad-title&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/nekretnine/prodaja-stanova/direktna-prodaja/5425435147525&quot;&gt;DIREKTNA PRODAJA&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;ul class=&quot;subtitle-places&quot;&gt;&lt;li&gt;Beograd&amp;nbsp;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Opština Zvezdara&amp;nbsp;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Mirijevo&amp;nbsp;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;p class=&quot;ad-description&quot;&gt;Hrastov parket,PVC stolarija,sigurnosna vrata,hodnik,spavaca soba,kupatilo,kuhinja sa prirodnom ventilacijom,dnevni boravak..klima..&lt;/p&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;clear&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;clear&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;","DoNotShowContactButton":null,"ContactButtonLink":null,"OtherFields":{"broj_soba_s":"2.0","grejanje_s":"EG","grad_s":"Beograd","lokacija_s":"Opština Zvezdara","mikrolokacija_s":"Mirijevo","kvadratura_d":39.0,"oglasivac_nekretnine_s":"Vlasnik","stanje_objekta_s":"Izvorno stanje","tip_nekretnine_s":"Stan","cena_d":31000.0,"dodatno_ss":["Odmah useljiv","Uknjižen"],"ostalo_ss":["Klima","Telefon","KATV","Internet","Interfon","Parking","Francuski balkon"],"tip_objekta_s":"Novogradnja","sprat_s":"3","sprat_od_s":"3","broj_soba_id_l":401,"grejanje_id_l":1543,"grad_id_l":35112,"lokacija_id_l":40788,"mikrolokacija_id_l":531542,"oglasivac_nekretnine_id_l":387237,"stanje_objekta_id_l":260581,"tip_nekretnine_id_l":8100000,"dodatno_id_ls":[12000001,12000004],"ostalo_id_ls":[12100002,12100010,12100011,12100012,12100013,12100017,12100018],"tip_objekta_id_l":387235,"sprat_id_l":12441300,"sprat_od_id_l":12441350,"broj_soba_order_i":4,"sprat_order_i":13,"kvadratura_d_unit_s":"m2","cena_d_unit_s":"EUR","defaultunit_kvadratura_d":39.0,"defaultunit_cena_d":31000.0,"_version_":1570636437658796032},"IsVerificationPending":false,"VerificationStateId":2,"InfoMessage":null,"TotalViews":21098,"TopCategoryCSSClass":null,"JobApplicationCount":0,"ShowAdvertiserAdsLink":false,"ShowMyAvatar":true,"IsOwnedByCurrentUser":false,"ThreeDTourExists":false,"UseRaiffeisenCreditCalculator":false,"CreditInstalment":null,"CreditTotalAmount":null}; for (var i in QuidditaEnvironment.CurrentClassified.OtherFields) { QuidditaEnvironment.CurrentClassified[i] = QuidditaEnvironment.CurrentClassified.OtherFields[i]; };
QuidditaEnvironment.IsUserOperator=false

QuidditaEnvironment.CurrentClassifiedInstances=[{"RelativeUrl":null,"HasAutomaticRenewal":false,"ValidToProlonged":null,"ShowInUnifiedAdvertiserAdList":false,"IsUsedMoveToTop":false,"ExpiresWithin48Hours":false,"UniqueId":null,"Id":null,"AdKindId":"4","IsPromoted":false,"IsInterestingInternal":false,"IsInterestingExternal":false,"InterestingEntryDate":null,"AdKindCode":"Premium","AdKindPosition":1,"StateId":101,"StoppageReasonIds":null,"StoppageReasonDescription":null,"Version":0,"Stamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","AdvertiserId":null,"Title":"DIREKTNA PRODAJA","Text":null,"TextHtml":null,"PrintText":null,"ContactInfoName":null,"PhoneNumber1":null,"PhoneNumber2":null,"Email":null,"Address":null,"City":null,"ValidFrom":"2017-06-16T13:10:11Z","ValidFromForDisplay":null,"ValidFromProlonged":null,"ValidTo":"2017-06-23T13:10:11Z","LastPublished":"2017-06-16T13:10:11Z","IsFirstOfKind":false,"CreatedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","LastModifiedAt":null,"IsArchived":false,"GeoLocationRPT":null,"ImageCount":null,"ImageURLs":null,"ImageTexts":null,"CategoryIds":null,"CategoryId":0,"CategoryHierarchyId":null,"CategoryNames":["Nekretnine","Stambeni prostor","Prodaja","Stan"],"CategoryFullName":null,"AdvertiserLogoUrlInternal":null,"AdvertiserLogoUrl":null,"VideoUrl":null,"CreatedByUserId":0,"DeclarationId":null,"EnclosureFilePath":null,"ListHTML":null,"GridHTML":null,"DoNotShowContactButton":null,"ContactButtonLink":null,"OtherFields":null,"IsVerificationPending":false,"VerificationStateId":0,"InfoMessage":null,"TotalViews":0,"TopCategoryCSSClass":null,"JobApplicationCount":0,"ShowAdvertiserAdsLink":false,"ShowMyAvatar":false,"IsOwnedByCurrentUser":false,"ThreeDTourExists":false,"UseRaiffeisenCreditCalculator":false,"CreditInstalment":null,"CreditTotalAmount":null}</script>]
```

I am using python, Selenium and phantom.js takes too long to scrape the data. Is it possible to extract the data by parsing this inline javascript from source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, yes.

Incredibly painful, also yes.

In the simple case, you could just do a simple regex check. Get the contents of the `<script>` tag then just look for something like `/[a-z][a-z0-9\.]+\s*=\s*(.*);/`. However, that regex will definitely not get every case.

From there, you'd have to have things to handle other cases, do things like identify and parse JSON, etc.

By the time you're done, you'll have nearly written an entire JS parser.

One possible route you could go beyond Selenium and Phantom.JS would be to try to feed it to a Node process and then look at what globals it set. However, as is the case with the example snippet, it may (and would) throw some errors so that may not work.

In all honesty, your best bet to use something like Selenium or Phantom.js and to figure out how to make them fast enough for you.